# Comparing series with missing values due to timeouts

Tags: survival, descriptive-statistics

I'm interested in comparing the result of two experiments. These experiments measure the completion time of a process. My problem is that these completion times are highly variable, and it's not always possible to run an experiment to completion.

To make it concrete, here is the type of data I get when repeating an experiment 10 times:

```
A  231  669  719  892 1072 1771 2830    *    *    *
B 1296 1667 2734    *    *    *    *    *    *    *
```

In this case, experiment A completed in 7/10 runs. Three runs had to be aborted. This means I don't know how long the completion time would be, only that it is larger than 3600 seconds. Experiment B finished in 3/10 runs and had to be aborted in 7 cases.

Clearly the process in experiment A seems "faster" than the process in experiment B. I'm interested in the best way of comparing them and determine *how much faster* A is.

A few ideas I've had:

- Compare medians (1422 vs "at least 3600" => at least 2.5x faster)
  However, if I compute a confidence interval for the median (using bootstrap and replacing "*" by 3600), it includes 3600 even for series A. So I guess I don't know enough about the median to make such a claim.
- Assume the data fits some distribution, and estimate its parameters.
  However, assuming a distribution seems like a strong assumption. And I wouldn't know how to estimate the parameters in the presence of timeouts, either.
- Just plotting the data and rely on visual comparison.

None of these seem convincing to me. So I come here for help. What is a strong statement about A vs B that I can confidently make?

Comment: These data are not missing: they are *censored.*  Click through the [tag:survival] tag to find posts about survival analysis, which is the discipline of analyzing such data.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. This seems to be what I need, and I would not have found that search term without help. I will try to solve my problem using survival analysis techniques.